# Selenium c# wait.until(expectedconditions)... function fails to find objects/elements on screen

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, wait

I am new to using selenium `Webdriver` and writing `c#`. I was using lots of `thread.sleep()` commands in my script to make sure Selenium didn't try and click too quick. Upon lots of research I found this is frowned upon and there are "better" ways to do it, so I started to use:-

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("FieldId")));
```

*Wait* is defined in another class as:-

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10));
```

I can only get this to work 2/10 times of running the script without getting :

> No such element exception: cannot locate element......

I have tons of examples of this problem now I have stopped using `thread.sleep`. After lots of research I always come to find this is the advised way but it seems totally unreliable. Have I missed something? The element is always there after 2 seconds and the error occurs before 10sec has passed. I have read at least 10 other posts which sound similar but none of them have a solution which works...except `Thread.Sleep(5000)` !

Comment: If you are using `WebDriverWait`, how could you get `No such element exception` while it throws `TimeoutException`??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur `Until()` throws exceptions if they are not in ignore list

Comment: Are you using an implicitwait also? You can get unexpected results if you use both implicit and explicit waits at the same time.

Comment: @JeffC - First of all, thank you for offering your assistance. I am not using another type of wait at the same point. I have tried using it, but this is currently the only "wait" process I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the NoSuchElementException type to the IgnoreExceptionTypes of the waiter after you create it.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("FieldId")));
```

In general, if the waiter is returning before the timeout you indicate is expired, it's because an exception occurred that is not currently ignored.

The [WebDriverWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/support/UI/WebDriverWait.cs) class is derived from the [DefaultWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/support/UI/DefaultWait%7BT%7D.cs) class. Both of which  you can review on github which I found really helpful in understanding how to use it.

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct, except exception type should be `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @kovpaev-alexey Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @digitalnoiz thanks for that. I will try and add that to my ignores and see if that does help solve the issue. When I have done that I will not here if it has worked. Thank you for your advice either way.